# Tensorflow: Building graph and label files form checkpoint file

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to build the graph and labels file from **inception-resnet-v2.ckpt** file. I have already downloaded the check point file form
`wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.tar.gz`.

I want to replace the **inception5h** model in **tensorflow: android camera domo** app with **inception-resnet-v2**. which requires a `MODEL_FILE` and a `LABEL_FILE` .

Now I don't know how I can get a .pb file and a label files from a checkpoint file.
I am learning tensorflow, still at beginner level.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what the label file is, but to convert a checkpoint into a .pb file (which is binary protobuf), you have to [freeze the graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/tool_developers/index.html#freezing). Here is a script I use for it:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# The script combines graph definition and trained weights into
# a single binary protobuf with constant holders for the weights.
# The resulting graph is suitable for the processing with other tools.


TF_HOME=~/tensorflow/

if [ $# -lt 4 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 graph_def snapshot output_nodes output.pb"
    exit 0
fi

proto=$1
snapshot=$2
out_nodes=$3
out=$4

$TF_HOME/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=$proto \
    --input_checkpoint=$snapshot \
    --output_graph=$out \
    --output_node_names=$out_nodes
```

Here, proto is a Graph definition (text protobuf), and snapshot is a checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Dmytro. But this not help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to optimize your model after you have frozen it.

Look at this great [tutorial](https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/)

For the labels you can get them [here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/datasets/inception/imagenet_class_names.txt) (credits to [Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052289.do) )

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference

bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output=/tf_files/optimized_graph.pb \
--input_names=Mul \
--output_names=final_result
```